# Gerar nome aleatório no MySQL - Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Boa noite, há alguma maneira de gerar nomes aleatórios com stored procedure no MySQL?
Tenho a seguinte tabela:

> ALUNO(id:int[PK], nome(varchar(100)), idade: int, Cr(float))

Preciso popular essa tabela com 10mil entradas. 
Para gerar os números aleatórios encontrei a função **RAND()** do MySQL, porém não encontrei nada relacionado à VARCHAR aleatório com Store Procedure.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa aqui:http://thecodecave.com/downloads/NameGeneration.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira que encontrei e nada elegante foi a seguinte.

Utilizar o a função **substring()** em conjunto com a **rand()** para selecionar uma letra aleatoriamente dentre todas as do alfabeto que passei como argumento.
Após isso usar a função **concat()** para concatenar todas as letras em uma só.

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists projBD.populaAluno $$
create procedure populaAluno()
begin   
declare nome varchar(100);
declare idade int ;
declare cr float;
declare counter int default 0;
while counter <= 10000 do
    set nome = concat(substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1),
                  substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', rand()*28, 1)
            ) ;     
     set idade = floor(1 + (rand() * 99));
     set cr = rand()*10 ;
    insert into ALUNO (nome,idade,cr) 
    values (nome,idade,cr);
    set counter = counter + 1;
    end while;
End $$
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Já pensou em utilizar uma ferramenta como o http://www.generatedata.com ? ele pode gerar saídas em vários formatos, inclusive SQL

Comment: Então, o exercício somente mencionava inserir 10k alunos aleatórios utilizando stored procedure. Não falava sobre inserção de dados de fora.
Contudo, essa é uma excelente ferramenta! Vou salvar aqui este link.